# Session based table zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

may I know how to create a session-based table using Zend Framework? It is because I am required to develop a shopping cart for my project in college.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can I suggest an alternative rather relying on session-based tables?

Comment: Ok. I am fine with that too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a component in ZF for storing sessions in the database, see: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html

once you have that setup you just store your shopping cart data in the session using `Zend_Session_Namespace` as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have 'virtual tables', which ideally we use for shopping carts.
Having sessions structured into tables, well, that is kinda mess?

Anyways,
The code should be:

```
$DBconfig = $this->getAdapter()->getConfig();
$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $DBconfig);
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE virtual_table ("`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product` VARCHAR(255), `productQty` INT(5) )";
// Setting values
$sql = "INSERT INTO virtual_table "......
```

and so on...

Results can be stored in Sessions using [Zend_Session_Namespace](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html)

[Here is a link](http://morgandavison.com/2011/06/temporary-tables-in-zend-framework/) to a wonderful article, which you might want to refer being a beginner in ZF?